# How to call a method after delay by gcd in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any why to call a method after 2second with dispatch, just like performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: ?

Comment: StackOverflow has a search function. Use it. Google also works.

Comment: Yes that link solved my problem.. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can,

#### Swift 3, Swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    <# YOUR CODE HERE #>
}
```

#### Swift 2

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        <# YOUR CODE HERE #>
}
```

#### Objective C

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <# YOUR CODE HERE #>
});
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be  more useful if you explain how this code works.

Comment: For more information about GCD, Refer link: [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after)

Comment: thanks @mehulsojitra this code works..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can add a delay to perform GCD with following code

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 // Do you work over here
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_time_t deferTime = 2.0f;
dispatch_after(deferTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//call you method here
});
```